# Is it possible to combine values in an array using VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and I'm stuck.. 
I have a table with workers and the amount of time they have been working. I want to insert all the workers into an array with the total time they have been working and then print out them into another sheet.

[image: Example of table:]

The problem is that I don't know if it's even possible to insert these values together into an array.. Right now I have hard-coded the names into my code and use If-statements to add hours to the right name but that will be a problem if I add more workers to the table (because then I need to add those names into the code too). I don't want the code to know the names or how many workers there are before it runs.

I want the print-out to be like:

```
Steve | 13
Emma  | 2
Andy  | 3
Jeff  | 12
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: First you have to show us [what you've tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: one cannot "print out them into another sheet"; please clarify this: just "print out"? paste? another work(sheet)?...

Comment: Well I'm sorry about that.. but as I stated in the text I was only able to write the names as integers and then make If-statements to collect the data. If I understood how arrays worked in vba I would try my best to do it by myself.. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this or something like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim Dic As Object, oCell As Range, i&, y%, key As Variant
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    y = 1: i = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each oCell In Range("A2:A" & i)
        If Not Dic.exists(oCell.Value) Then
            Dic.Add oCell.Value, WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("A2:A" & i), oCell.Value, Range("B2:B" & i))
        End If
    Next
    For Each key In Dic
        Debug.Print key, Dic(key)
    Next
End Sub
```

here the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was actually able to solve the problem with your help. As a java/C# programmer I can't believe how hard it is to do something like this in vba..

Comment: Nice dictionary approach up one :)

Answer (score 1):

Very simple way:

```
Function GetTable(r As Range) As Variant
GetTable = r.Value
End Function

Sub main()
Dim Table As Variant
Table = GetTable(ActiveSheet.Range("A2:B6")) 'Supply the range of your workers.
For i = 1 To UBound(Table, 1)
Sum = Sum + Table(i, 2)
Next
MsgBox (Sum)
End Sub
```

ouput:
[image]

Comment: Is there any need for the `GetTable()` UDF? Just assign the value directly to get the array...

Answer (score 0):

Just use a PivotTable and if necessary have the PivotTable automatically refresh when the sheet is clicked.